# does adding element to a set return true if it is successful in python?

Tags: python, list, function, set, addition

To my understanding, adding elements to a `set` does not return anything.
eg:

```
>>> s=set([1,2,3])
>>> s.add(1)
>>> b = s.add(1)
>>> b
>>> b = s.add(5)
>>> b
>>> print b
None
>>> b = s.add(5)
>>> print b
None
```

but I am confused how this function to [remove duplicates of a list while preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order?rq=1) works:

```
def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
```

not seen_add(x) return true always irrespective of if I add duplicates or not.
The only real check is if `x not in seen`, since if that fails, it will not perform `not see_add(x)`.

Is my understanding here or am I missing something?

however, here, `not seen_add(1)` return true if I add duplicate or a unique element.
This is puzzling, so is the `not` here just do an empty check? but `seen_add()` is not returning a set to do an `empty` check. and why `seen_add(2)` does not return anything but `not seen_add(1)` returns the `boolean True`

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> seen_add=seen.add
>>> seen_add(1)
>>> seen
set([1])
>>> seen.add(2)
>>> seen
set([1, 2])
>>> not seen_add(1)
True
>>> not seen_add(4)
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have discovered, `seen_add(x)` always returns `None`.

Now, `not None` is `True`:

```
>>> not None
True
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> **5.1. Truth Value Testing**
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - ...

Since `not seen_add(x)` is always `True`, it has no effect on the result of the `if`. It is only used for the side effect of adding `x` to `seen`.

Put another way, the following:

```
seen_add = seen.add
return [ x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
```

is a shorter (and likely more performant) way to write:

```
result = []
for x in seq:
  if x not in seen:
    result.append(x)
    seen.add(x)
return result
```

Comment: while this works, is this right way. because the `not seen_add(x)` is always `True`, then why check it on `if`

Comment: @eagertoLearn: Because you can't put statements inside a list comprehension, only expressions.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain how boolean tests shortcut.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I was going to, but then decided it was not relevant here (since calling `seen_add(x)` is a no-op if `x` is already in `seen`). I have a feeling that trying to explain short-circuiting would muddy the waters even further...

Comment: @NPE: Thanks, I do know about `short-circuiting`. I was just confused as to why something that always return `True` is part of the `if`. but it is simply because `list comprehension takes expressions` as you pointed out. and pointing out that `not None` is `True` which is not same in Java, that I am familiar with

Answer (score 3):

As said by the others, `not seen_add(x)` always evaluates to `True`, so it is used only as a hack to add the addition statement into the list comprehension. Since the logic value of `x and True` is equal to `x`, this does not change the behavior of the `if`.

Another thing that this does, due to the [short-circuit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) behavior of `and`, is that the right-hand argument to `and` is only executed if the left-hand argument is `True`. So the call to `seen.add()` is only done when the element is not yet in the set.

The equivalent python code would be:

```
def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen:
            result.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    return result
```

The solution with the list comprehension might be faster, but it is too cryptic to my taste.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `not None` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
def add_ok(set, value):
    return len(set) != (set.add(value), len(set))[1]


print(add_ok(a, 1))
print(add_ok(a, 1))
```